# react-hook-form validation not working with custom fields array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hook-form

I am using react-hook-form with custom dynamic input fields array, it looks like the validation is working when I click on submit button, but it doesn't show the error messages, I am creating the state as:

```
const [formFields, setFormFields] = useState([
{
  height: 45,
  label: "tv",
  placeholder: "555",
  name: "tv",
  maxWidth: 203,
  error: errors.tv,
  value: ""
},
{
  height: 45,
  label: "radio",
  placeholder: "90%",
  name: "radio",
  maxWidth: 126,
  error: errors.radio,
  value: ""
},
{
  height: 45,
  label: "instagram",
  placeholder: "90%",
  name: "instagram",
  maxWidth: 126,
  error: errors.instagram,
  value: ""
}
```

]);

and creating the input as:

```
{formFields.map((item, index) => {
      return (
        <div key={index}>
          <TextInput
            name={item.name}
            label={item.label}
            height={item.height}
            placeholder={item.placeholder}
            error={item.error}
            value={item.value}
            inputRef={register({
              required: true
            })}
            onChange={fieldOnChange(index)}
          />
          {item.error && <span>Enter a valide value</span>}
        </div>
      );
    })}
```

you can check the [demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/wandering-rain-dxflt)

any help please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because you formFields in useState. It runs only one time. Show it already captures errors value i.e first initially value. You need to either use useEffect to keep track change of error value or change condition of item.error to directly errors.

`react-hook-form` uses its errors for validation i.e in your case it should be

```
{errors[item.name] && <span>Enter a valid value</span>}
```

Here is demo link : https://codesandbox.io/s/blue-shape-pv8jf